# Select and rewrite value in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to do that "Zero" and "Three" = "null" in $mas?
Not changing $result

```
$result = array(1,2);
$mas = array("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three");
foreach ($result as $row) {

    if ($row != array_search($mas[$row], $mas)) {
    $mas[$row];
    } else {
    $mas[$row] = 'null';
    }
}
print_r($mas);
```

Comment: You can use this to replace $mas value:if (isset($mas[$row])){$mas[$row]=null;},  more better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try using `in_array()`. Like this

```
$result = array(1, 2);
$mas = array("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three");
foreach ($mas as $key=>$row) {
    if(!in_array($key, $result)){
        $mas[$key] = 'null';
    }
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($mas);
print '</pre>';
```